# Odd MapReduce output

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing a MapReduce process and got some odd result. 
The expected result is :

```
{ "_id" : {...}, "value" : { "register" : 1, "login" : 3, "payment" : 4.99, "transaction" : 1} }
```

What I got is :

```
{ "_id" : {...}, "value" : { "register" : 1, "login" : 6, "payment" : 4.99, "transaction" : 0, "transcation" : NaN } }
```

Everything looks right except "transcation", the first "transaction":0 should be ...:1, the second transaction:NaN should NOT exist.

I print all the log but didn't find anything wrong.

Code:

```
exports.basic = function(){

    var map = function(){
        var key = {
            app:this.properties.YA0token,
            uuid:this.properties.distinct_id
        }
        var value = {
            register:0,
            login:0,
            payment:0,
            transaction:0
        };


        if (this.event=='register') {
            value.register = 1;
        } else if (this.event=='login') {
            value.login = 1;
        } else if (this.event=='YA0charge') {
            value.payment = this.properties.amount;
            value.transaction = 1;
            print(value.register,value.login,value.payment,value.transaction);
        }


        emit(key,value);
    }

    var reduce = function(key,values){
        var result = {
            register:0,
            login:0,
            payment:0,
            transaction:0
        };
        print("values.length = ",values.length);

        values.forEach(function(value){
            result.register += value.register;
            result.login += value.login;
            result.payment += value.payment;
            result.transcation += value.transcation;
            if (value.payment>0) print('value:',value.register,value.login,value.payment,value.transaction);
        });
        return result;
    }


    var options = {
        out:{merge:"mr_users"},
        query:{
            "event":{$in:["register","login","YA0charge"]},
            "properties.time": {"$gte": new Date("9 1 2013"), "$lt": new Date("9 3 2013")}
        }
    }

    eventCollection.mapReduce(map,reduce,options,function (err, collection2) {
        logger.info('MapReduce for basic is done.');
        collection2.find().toArray(function(err,item){
            logger.silly(item);
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a mix of `transcation` and `transaction` field names in your code.  Note the transposed `c` and `a` in the first one.